# ASP.NET Databind combobox

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu, combobox, datasource

After inserting a new object i want to see that object in a combobox. I do this by setting the datasource again and rebinding the combobox.

In debug-mode I see the new object in the datasource, but on my page I don't.

For example:
I got a combobox with Persons: Elise, Jayson, Marc, ...
I add a new Person 'Charlotte', I rebind the combobox but I don't see the new person in the list.

Code:

```
ddl.DataTextField = "Name";
ddl.DataValueField = "ID";

List <Person> persons = ws.GetAllPersons();
persons.Insert(0, new Person() { ID= -1, Name = "Choose person" });

ddl.DataSource = persons;
ddl.DataBind();
```

For now I just refresh the page by using  'Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);'

Thanks.

EDIT: 
- I have tried the updatepannel but with no succes ...

Answer (score 0):

do it in [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx) 
and just

```
myUpdatePanel.Update();
```